# Translate the allowed values list of an entity access field?

Tags: 8

I have a field of type: `Entity access field`.

In my allowed values list I have:

```
public|Public
community|Community
```

I have all of the core translation modules enabled:

- Configuration Translation
- Content Translation
- Interface Translation
- Language

I cannot find where in the administrative interface to translate these. Can they be translated in the interface?

Comment: You can translate the allowed values list in the Field UI. When *Configuration Translation* is enabled you should find a tab "Translate content fields" directly to the right of "Field settings".

Comment: I have that. The translation options I have are for the label and the help text, nothing for the list values?

Comment: Yes, this is the right place, below there should be the translation of the allowed value list, if it is a list field. But what is an "entity access field? Where did you place the field?

Answer (score 1):

As @4k4 already said in his comment, if you have the Configuration Translation module enabled, you simply go to *your-site*/en/admin/structure/types/manage/*your-content-type*/fields and select the list field you want to translate (see screenshot below). [image]